# Rails HABTM with join table get non associated records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am using Rails 5 with postgresql 9.6. I have the following model and relationships

**Tables**

1. people
2. segments
3. people_segments (join table)

> Relationships

**person:**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :segments, through: :people_segments
```

**segment:**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :people, through: :people_segments
```

Here I want to get the people who not associated with particular segment. I tried using join but could not get result. Now I am using "not in" query and it took more time. Is there any other way without using "not in"?

Comment: "Here I want to get the people who not associated with particular segment. I tried using join but could not get result." -> what was the Activerecord query you wrote, what did you expect, what did you get?

Answer (score 2):

your objects are wrong

the model is `person` and the table is `people`

Model Person.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :segments
```

Model Segment.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :people
```

The migration looks like this

```
class CreatePeopleAndSegments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :segments do |t|
      t.string :part_number
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :people_segments, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :person, index: true
      t.belongs_to :segment, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

So when you do `@person.segments` you get an array including all the segments *viceversa* `@segment.people`

> Here I want to get the people who not associated with particular segment. I tried using join but could not get result. Now I am using "not in" query and it took more time. Is there any other way without using "not in"?

Between the two tables there is already a `Join`, maybe your best choice is making sure you can use that join as `Model` in the application side.

There is a specific chapter in the *association_basics* guide from rails discussing about this, it is called [choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

I quote them

> The simplest rule of thumb is that **you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity**. If you don't need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember to create the joining table in the database).

I believe that if you read that chapter you will understand the best choice for you is using `has_many :through` and having an object in your Application that represents the table `people_segments`.

Think with creativity what is this relationship, is this relationship between `people` and `segments` a `role` or a `position`...

To implement `has_many :through` you can follow the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Once you have done that, you can use the `Position` object to do the query.

```
Position.where.not(segment_id: 1)
```

If this is not what you need, the [rails query documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) includes many more info and StackOverflow does not substitute the official documentation

Comment: @anandh does this not solve your problem? why don't you accept the response? Thanks

Comment: Yes, your answer does't solve my problem. But I voted for your effort. Still searching for the solution...